# minidlna.conf path to a different drive

Tags: 20.04, mediaserver, dlna, minidlna

can someone please tell me what is wrong with how I configured the path o a second HDD in my minidlna.conf?
I get the following:

```
[2020/06/25 17:11:27] minidlna.c:623: fatal: Media directory entry not understood [B,/mnt/sdb1/Media]
```

the configuration is as follows:

```
media_dir=V,/home/guest/files/MediaSERV/Videos
media_dir=A,/home/guest/files/MediaSERV/Music
media_dir=P,/home/guest/files/MediaSERV/Pictures

#media_dir=V,/mnt/sdb1/Media/Downloads
#media_dir=V,/mnt/sdb1/Media/Series
media_dir=V,/mnt/sdb1/Media
```

I have also attempted /dev/sdb1/ , didn't work either and I can't find any other way to point to the drive in question.
Thank you

Ubuntu 20.04

```
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0   931G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465,8G  0 part /mnt/sdb1
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I have reduced the complete minidlna.conf file to:

```
media_dir=V,/home/MediaSERV/Videos
media_dir=A,/home/MediaSERV/Music
media_dir=P,/home/MediaSERV/Pictures

media_dir=V,/mnt/sdb1/Media/Downloads
media_dir=V,/mnt/sdb1/Media/Series

db_dir=/home/MediaSERV/cache

log_dir=/home/MediaSERV/log

port=8200

friendly_name=MyMedia

inotify=yes

album_art_names=Cover.jpg/cover.jpg/AlbumArtSmall.jpg/albumartsmall.jpg
album_art_names=AlbumArt.jpg/albumart.jpg/Album.jpg/album.jpg
album_art_names=Folder.jpg/folder.jpg/Thumb.jpg/thumb.jpg
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /mnt/sdb1/Media'?

Comment: root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver# ls -ld /mnt/sdb1/Media
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 jun 24 21:36 /mnt/sdb1/Media
root@ubuserv:/home/homeserver#

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
media_dir=B,/mnt/sdb1/Media
```

cannot be understood because `B` [is not a valid type](https://sourceforge.net/p/minidlna/git/ci/v1_0_21/tree/minidlna.c#l454).

Check the [sample minidlna.conf](https://sourceforge.net/p/minidlna/git/ci/v1_0_21/tree/minidlna.conf) to know more about valid types.

```
# set this to the directory you want scanned.
# * if have multiple directories, you can have multiple media_dir= lines
# * if you want to restrict a media_dir to a specific content type, you
#   can prepend the type, followed by a comma, to the directory:
#   + "A" for audio  (eg. media_dir=A,/home/jmaggard/Music)
#   + "V" for video  (eg. media_dir=V,/home/jmaggard/Videos)
#   + "P" for images (eg. media_dir=P,/home/jmaggard/Pictures)
```

Comment: the B was a typo, I have corrected it but still not working

Comment: But now that you've corrected that, you still get the same error you posted?

Comment: I am not getting errors but the server is still not seen on other devices, and the http://192.168.0.xx:8200/ MiniDLNA status shows
Media library
Audio files 0
Video files 0
Image files 0

Comment: This question has been answered. I suggest you accept the answer and open a new one with the new problem, because it is not related to the one in this question. One problem -> one question is something that helps us all keep the answers discoverable.